# Only numbers function

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function to let the user enter only numbers. I need this function to let me enter "," and ";". How do I do this? Under the my function.

```
function SomenteNumero(e){
     var tecla=(window.event)?event.keyCode:e.which;   
    if((tecla>47 && tecla<58)) return true;
    else{
        if (tecla==8 || tecla==0) return true;
    else  return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to map it to the correct ASCII character. See: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: This is the third post I've seen with people filtering by *ascii* char-code - it's a terrible idea!  Where are you getting these examples from?

Answer (score 1):

Please do not try to validate input using ASCII values. It is prone to errors and probably does not reliably determine what you are actually trying to. This is probably closer to something you need:

```
function isNumber(str) {
    return /^[0-9,;]+$/.test(str);
}
```

Keep in mind that this example is probably not comprehensive. Your specifications would need to be a lot more detailed for it to fully suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You need define on object. Try

```
`<script>
function NumberBox(e){
 var _define=(window.event)?event.keyCode:e.which;
 if((_define>47 && _define<58)) return true;
 else{
 if (_define==8 || _define==0) return true;
 else  return false;
 }
}
</script>`
```

Then

`<input name="Name" type="text" id="Name" size="15" maxlength="30" onkeypress="return NumberBox(event);">`